# Paypal Sandbox: An internal service error has occurred

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I am trying to make first call with Rest Api Sdk PHP as wrote [hear](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/).
Receiving always `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR`

```
debug_id for example: 16d1628fcae04
```

Comment: Post some code, show what's the problem..

Comment: See, how looking through the code sometimes provides the solution :)
It's good to answer your question by yourself, by providing the solution as an answer, not just updating the question. This way nobody will lose time looking at your problem..

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I forgot:

```
$payment->setTransactions(...);
```

before  calling

```
$payment->create($apiContext);
```

Without transaction endpoint returns `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` and not as expected `VALIDATION_ERROR` or `MALFORMED_REQUEST`

Fixing this solved the problem.